# Deleting empty files with only header record

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to delete all the files in a folder which only contains a header record and no data in it. I wrote the following code to do it.

`'for file in <Path>FileName*.csv; do [[ $(wc -l "$file" | cut -d' ' -f1) -eq 1 ]] && echo "rm $file" ; done'`

But this gives me an error *rm: cannot remove ‘rm’: No such file or directory*

Any ideas how to fix this.

Comment: You are echoing the command and not running it?

Comment: But the files are getting deleted and throwing that error also with that command

Comment: @Nikhil : Please post the actual code you are executing. What you posted is simply a long string within single quotes and as such can't be executed. In addition, specify the shell you are using. You tagged it as Posix Shell, but Posix does not allow `[[...]]`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy&paste the output of `ls -l <Path>FileName*.csv` and the output of your script as shown with `echo "rm $file"` including error messages (if any).

Comment: Assuming that the single quotes should be back-quotes… If there are three files, the back-quotes convert it to `rm file1.csv rm file2.csv rm file3.csv` which attempts to remove `rm` (twice) as well as three files. Don't use the outer backticks. Replace the `echo "rm $file"` with `rm "$file"`. Or, if you must use the backticks, then `echo "rm '$file';"` to place semicolons between the commands, which makes things work even when the backticks (command substitution) flattens the output. My single quotes will help you if file names contain spaces etc, but not if the names contain single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that with a loop.  Use something like:

```
find . -name 'FileName*.csv' -type f -exec sh -c 'test $(wc -l < "$1") = 1' _ {} \; -delete
```